# DDR3 Graphics card to DDR2 RAM

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, motherboard

I would like to ask you if it will fit the graphics card with my memory Ram, I have the data Habits: motherboard: GA-945GCM-S2L RAM: 2 x1Gb kingston DDR2 (333) mhz serial number: B83B053A and I say I buy a graphics card:

ASUS RADEON R5 230 R5230-SL-1GD3-L 1GB DDR3 PCI-E RETAIL CPU: intel pentium E2180 2.00 Ghz overlock to 2.50 Ghz and I want to ask if you would work properly the graphics card the systems that I have, thank you for understanding

Answer (score 3):

Having neither the GPU nor the motherboard, I can't tell you for sure if it will work, but I can tell you this:

The memory type on a dedicated graphics card does not relate to the memory type of the system/processor, and if the motherboard has a PCI-E slot for the graphics card, I would generally expect them to be compatible.

Graphics memory is used by the GPU, and system memory is used by the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

It would *absolutely* work. Your video card more often than not uses a different type of ram (GDDRx) from your system anyway.

DDR3 is a lower performing (but cooler running) alternative for GDDR4/5 (or various other numbers) used in passively cooled cards or to cut costs. The DDR3 in this case is used by your GPU not your video card and would work.

I'm running a [gforce 450 varient](http://www.asus.com/Graphics_Cards/ENGTS450_DC_SLDI1GD3/) which uses DDR3 on an older system with ddr3 ram on the main board

Comment: You mean we could use GDDR5 in our normal ram slots ( on motherboard ) if rams could have enough cooling?

Comment: Nope, your memory controller wouldn't support it. The real point I was trying to make is the sort of RAM used by a system does not affect a discrete GPU in any way.